# SQL query not displaying row which is null

Tags: sql-server, pivot

This is the SQL query I am trying to execute :

```
SELECT
    VisitID,
    VisitDate,
    IssuedBy,
    VisitPurpose,
    CompanyName,
    SPname as 'SalePerson',
    [1] as 'Person 1',
    [2] as 'Person 2',
    [3] as 'Person 3'
FROM (
        SELECT
            TD.VisitID,
            TD.VisitDate,
            TD.IssuedBy,
            TD.VisitPurpose,
            TC.CompanyName,
            SP.SPname,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TD.VisitID ORDER BY TE.AlongwithID) AS EngineerNo,
            EN.[AlongwithName]
        FROM
            tblVisitTicket AS TD
            INNER JOIN tblVisit_Alongwith AS TE
                ON TD.VisitID = TE.VisitID
            INNER JOIN tblAlongWith AS EN
                ON TE.AlongwithID = EN.AlongwithID
            INNER JOIN tblCompany AS TC
                ON TD.CompanyID = TC.CompanyID
            INNER JOIN tblSalePerson AS SP
                ON TD.SalePersonID = SP.SalePersonID
        WHERE TD.VisitStatus = 1
    ) AS DT
    PIVOT(MAX([AlongwithName])
        FOR [EngineerNo]
        IN([1], [2], [3])
    ) AS PT
```

Now this is working perfectly however due to the design of my application there will be sometimes values in Person 1, 2 and 3 and sometimes there will be value in only 1 and 2 and sometimes in only 1 and sometimes there will be no value in any of them.

Now the problem is that if `Person 1`, `Person 2` and `Person 3` has null in all of them, the whole row will be skipped by the query. Why is that? How do I display result even when there is null in them.

Comment: format your question ...

Comment: Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I've just formatted your query, pleas do it next time to help your helpers :) Thanks

Comment: Possibly you need to replace one or several of your inner joins with outer ones. An example showing the wrong result and what was expected instead might help in finding the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could understand, you have made **inner join** between **tblVisitTicket** and **tblVisit_AlongWith** tables.
While there is possibility that tblvisit_Alongwith has no data for specific visit.

If I am right, then you problem can be solved by using **outer join** in these tables, so that all data of tblVisitTicket will be available and matching data of tblVisit_AlongWith will be there.